# Having trouble putting a <Tab> in a reusable function

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a tabs component and have been getting stumped.

The following example works as expected:

```
export default function ListOfTabs() {
  return(
    <Tabs>
      <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
        This be an example
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

However, when I put the  component into a reusable function like this:

```
function ReusableTabLink() {
  return(
    <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
      This be an example
    </Tab>
  )
}
```

And call it like so:

```
export default function ListOfTabs() {
  return(
      <Tabs>
        <ReusableTabLink />
      </Tabs>
  )
}
```

I see nothing displayed.

Comment: Have you tried removing the wrapping `div` in your ReusableTabLink? It wasn't there in the working snippet...

Comment: could you show when you call your method in the jsx or else ?

Comment: I did remove the <div> (just now) with the same outcome.

Comment: Unlike your other examples you aren't exporting `ReusableTabLink`

Comment: Are you importing React on your ReusableTabLink ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [the implementation](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Tabs.tsx) of `Tabs` in Bootstrap has very specific expectations for its use. :)

Basically, it is expecting the direct child to have the props it is looking for, and if it doesn't it won't work.  I put together [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-tree-drgh9?file=/src/App.js) where I passed the props directly to your custom component and the tab shows up.

I'm guessing if you want to do this you'll need to utilize the [custom tab layout](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-custom-layout) mechanism within `react-bootstrap`.  You could probably wrap that in your own `Tabs` component that would hopefully make more sense. :D

Here is an example from their docs:

```
<Tab.Container id="left-tabs-example" defaultActiveKey="first">
  <Row>
    <Col sm={3}>
      <Nav variant="pills" className="flex-column">
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="first">Tab 1</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="second">Tab 2</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={9}>
      <Tab.Content>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="first">
          <Sonnet />
        </Tab.Pane>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="second">
          <Sonnet />
        </Tab.Pane>
      </Tab.Content>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Tab.Container>
```

Comment: Interesting. Even in the Sandbox example the text itself doesn't even show up underneath the corresponding tab.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Probably because I didn't pass the `children` prop directly.

Comment: I updated the example to pass the children:  https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-tree-drgh9?file=/src/App.js